# C/GTK+3 draw event for multiple widgets

Tags: c, gtk, cairo

I am currently trying to learn GTK+3/cairo using C.
I have written a small application which draws a gauge face and needle on a gtk drawing area using cairo.

This works well so far, i have tried creating multiple drawing areas (multiple gauges) which
all have the same callback function for the draw event, this also works well with static values.

Now my question, i would like to be able to draw multiple gauges each with their own values. But how do i know in my callback function which gauge (drawing area) emitted the draw signal?
I guess this also includes how do i "create and store" data for the gauges so their properties can be fetched from within the draw callback.

I should probably create a struct that holds the data for a gauge, and create multiple of those. That's what i have gathered by looking at various projects that use GTK, but it's too complicated for me to fully understand how it works.

This is how i create the drawing area(s):

```
gaugearea1 = gtk_drawing_area_new();
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(hbox), gaugearea1, FALSE, FALSE, 5);
gtk_widget_set_size_request(gaugearea1, 300, 300);
gtk_widget_realize(gaugearea1);
g_signal_connect(gaugearea1, "draw", G_CALLBACK(draw_event), NULL);
```

And the callback function is written like this, pretty standard.

```
static gboolean draw_event(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr)
{
    GdkWindow *win;
    win = gtk_widget_get_window(widget);

    // Draw all arcs/lines using cr
}
```

Any tips on how to approach something like this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `GtkDrawingArea` that emits the signal is simply the `widget` you receive in your callback. Just cast it to the appropriate type, if needed.

But look carefully at the docs from the `draw` signal:

#### The "draw" signal

```
gboolean     user_function                  (GtkWidget    *widget,
                                            CairoContext *cr,
                                            gpointer      user_data) : Run Last
```

Your `draw_event` function is missing the last parameter, the `gpointer user_data`.

And that's the use of the last `NULL` parameter of the call to `g_signal_connect()`.
So you can put here a pointer to a struct with all the data you need.

Or you can use the `g_object_set_data()` function to attach a pointer to the widget, but I wouldn't recommend that for such a simple application.

If you have a fixed number of gauges, all is well: just create the same number of structs, but if your number of gauges is dynamic, you have to create the structs in the head, so a new problem arises: when do you free the data? The answer is in `g_signal_connect_data()`: this function receives an additional callback that is called when the struct is no longer needed.

Something like the follwoing:

```
struct GaugeData
{
    /* your data here */
};
static void gauge_data_free(gpointer ptr, GClosure *clo)
{
    struct GaugeData *data = ptr;
    /* free extra resources, if needed */
    g_free(data);
}
static gboolean draw_event(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer ptr)
{
    struct GaugeData *data = ptr;

    // Draw all arcs/lines using cr and data
}

void CreateOneGauge()
{
    gaugearea1 = gtk_drawing_area_new();
    struct GaugeData *data = g_new(GaugeData, 1);
    /* init the data */

    /* ... */
    g_signal_connect_data(gaugearea1, "draw", G_CALLBACK(draw_event), 
                data, gauge_data_free, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for an awesome answer, i will use a fixed number of gauges for the time being and have a look at creating them dynamically later.