# Rendering a GtkPixbuf in a GtkDrawingArea with C

Tags: c, multithreading, user-interface, gtk, gdk

So I am using C and I am trying to render a GtkPixbuf in a GtkDrawingArea. I have a GtkThread that should be in charge of forcing the draw every N seconds. I don't get any errors or warnings, but, my code still doesn't produce the intended results. Hence, I believe that I am missing something fundamental about how all this works.

My code is below:

```
#include <gtk.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define WIDTH 512
#define HEIGHT 512
#define CHANNELS 3
#define STEP (8*CHANNELS)


typedef struct pixbuf_data_s{

    unsigned char* data;    
    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;
    GtkWidget *drawing;

} pixbuf_data_t;


GdkPixbuf* create_and_set_pixbuf(unsigned char* data){

    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;
    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data(data, GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB, FALSE, 8, WIDTH, HEIGHT, STEP/8, NULL, NULL);

return pixbuf;
}

void create_image_data(unsigned char* data){

    int i,j,k;  
    unsigned char blue, red, green;

    //===Create A Random RGB Combo===//
    blue = (unsigned char)((rand()) % 255);
    green = (unsigned char)((rand()) % 255);
    red = (unsigned char)((rand()) % 255);

    for(i=0;i<HEIGHT;i++){
         for(j=0;j<WIDTH;j++){
            for(k=0;k<CHANNELS;k++){
                if (k == 0) data[i*STEP+j*CHANNELS+k] = red;                
                if (k == 1) data[i*STEP+j*CHANNELS+k] = green;
                if (k == 2) data[i*STEP+j*CHANNELS+k] = blue;
            }
        }
    }

    return;

}



pixbuf_data_t* create_pixbuf_data(){

    pixbuf_data_t* pixbuf_data = malloc(sizeof(pixbuf_data_t));

    //===Create PixBuf Data===//
    pixbuf_data->data = malloc( (WIDTH*HEIGHT*CHANNELS*STEP) * sizeof(unsigned char));
    create_image_data(pixbuf_data->data);
    pixbuf_data->pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data(pixbuf_data->data, GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB, FALSE, 8, WIDTH, HEIGHT, STEP/8, NULL, NULL);

    return pixbuf_data;

}



void draw_callback(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer ptr){

    pixbuf_data_t *pixbuf;
    pixbuf = (pixbuf_data_t*) ptr;

    //===Redo Image===//
    create_image_data(pixbuf->data);

    //===Set Source===//
    gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cr, pixbuf->pixbuf, 0, 0);

    //===Fill===//  
    cairo_fill(cr);

    return;
}


void *display_image_thread(gpointer in_data){

    pixbuf_data_t* pixbuf;
    pixbuf = g_object_get_data(G_OBJECT(in_data), "pixbuf");

    while(1){
        sleep(5);
        gtk_widget_queue_draw(GTK_WIDGET(pixbuf->drawing));
    }

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget  *window;
    GtkButton  *button;
    GtkImage   *image;
    GtkWidget  *drawing_area;
    GError     *error = NULL;
    GObject *object;    
    GThread   *thread;
    GdkPixbuf *pix_buf;
    pixbuf_data_t* pixbuf_data;

    //===Init Random Number Generator===//
    srand(time(NULL));

    //===Init GTK+===//
    gtk_init(NULL, NULL);

    //===Secure Glib and Gtk===/
    if(!g_thread_supported()){
        g_thread_init(NULL);
    }
    gdk_threads_init();

    //===Obtain gtk's global lock===//
    gdk_threads_enter();

    //===Create new GtkBuilder object===//
    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    if(!gtk_builder_add_from_file( builder, "draw_glade.glade", &error )){
        g_free(error);
        exit(1);
    }

    //===Get main window pointer from UI===//
    window = GTK_WIDGET( gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "main_window" ) );
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    //===Get Buttons===//
    button = GTK_BUTTON( gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "stop_button"));
    gtk_button_set_label(button, "STOP");
    button = GTK_BUTTON( gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "play_button"));
    gtk_button_set_label(button, "PLAY");
    button = GTK_BUTTON( gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "pause_button"));
    gtk_button_set_label(button, "PAUSE");
    button = GTK_BUTTON( gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "next_button"));
    gtk_button_set_label(button, "NEXT");

    //===Create Drawing Area and Callback===//
    drawing_area = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "main_drawing_area"));
    pixbuf_data = create_pixbuf_data();
    pixbuf_data->drawing = drawing_area;
    g_signal_connect(pixbuf_data->drawing, "draw", G_CALLBACK(draw_callback), pixbuf_data);

    //===Create new thread===//
    object = g_object_new(G_TYPE_OBJECT, NULL);
    g_object_set_data(G_OBJECT(object), "pixbuf", (gpointer) pixbuf_data);
    thread = g_thread_new(NULL, display_image_thread, (gpointer)object);
    if(!thread){
        printf("Bad Thread!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    //===Connect signals===//
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    //==Show window===//
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    //===Gtk Main Callback===//
    gtk_main();

    //===Release gtk's global lock===//
    gdk_threads_leave();

    //===Destroy builder===//
    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(builder));

    return 0;
}
```

The glade file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="main_window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="default_width">800</property>
    <property name="default_height">600</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkBox" id="right_vbox">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkDrawingArea" id="main_drawing_area">
            <property name="width_request">512</property>
            <property name="height_request">512</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">True</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkBox" id="play_button_box">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="stop_button">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">True</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="play_button">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">True</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">1</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
               <object class="GtkButton" id="pause_button">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">True</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">2</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="next_button">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives_default">True</property>
                <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">True</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">3</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">True</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

So what am I missing?

---

Sources I've used:

[C/GTK+3 draw event for multiple widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268637/c-gtk3-draw-event-for-multiple-widgets)

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkDrawingArea.html

https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Cairo-Interaction.html#gdk-cairo-set-source-pixbuf

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-queue-draw

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-draw

Comment: I don't think this is going to fix it but you seem to be going a bit too far with the thread safety stuff. Nothing in the `Secure Glib and Gtk` block is necessary, nor are the calls to `gdk_threads_enter()` or `gdk_threads_leave()` (in fact, they're deprecated!). And why are you building a new GObject to pass your pixbuf struct pointer around threads? You can send the pointer directly and it'd still work. Furthermore, you say you don't have compiler errors, but `display_image_thread()` returns a `void *` yet you use a bare `return;` at the end...?? Finally, what will this thread do eventually?

Comment: You cannot use GTK and GDK API from different threads. Don't use `gdk_thread_enter()/leave()`, as they are not portable. Create a thread, create the GdkPixbuf inside the thread, then use `g_idle_add()` or `g_main_context_invoke()` to call a function to update the UI.

Comment: I have been trying to piece this together from the fragments of the different Gtk/Gdk tutorials and gnome references that exist. This is my first Gtk program, so it likely is a collection of bad patterns and deprecated API.

Why I am not allowed to call Gtk/Gdk from a different thread? If that is the case, how am I supposed to call a function from said different thread to update the UI? Wouldn't that necessarily need to call Gtk/Gdk?

Comment: This example is an abstraction of some functionality I am trying to add to some existing code. I want to add a UI, and I have created an image that I want to display to the screen, which currently is just saved. 

So, this image gets updated somewhere else, and I need a module that will create a UI and update the image periodically, or maybe as soon as the data becomes available. Currently, I am going for the easier of the two, and will maybe switch later if it is too slow. Either way, working this out will show me how to get the pieces working together.

Comment: What is updating the image, out of curiosity? Is it some worker thread that interfaces with some outside-world thing or intensive calculation? Is it coming from the network? Or is it purely on a timeout?

Comment: The image can be updated by two things:

1. The 'intensive' calculation that is going on in the code already written. 
2. The user on the front end, which will press a button sequence (pause, then next) to prompt the backend to step through the calculation. Basically, to closely investigate when things start getting out of control.

The backend is working on a posix thread implementation, if that helps. There is a worker thread there which essentially prepares the data for processing as an image. I added another piece that prepares the image from the data. This is the image I want to display.