# gtkmm signal function must return "int"?

Tags: c++, cairo, glade, gtkmm3

I'm in the process of writing a program that is supposed to display the Sierpinski triangle. To this end, I first created a demonstration for cairo, since I've never worked with cairo before; it just creates one line:

```
#include <glibmm.h>
#include <gtkmm.h>

Gtk::Window* W_Main;
Gtk::DrawingArea* D_Triangle;
Gtk::Button* B_Draw;
Gtk::Adjustment* A_Depth;

int on_D_Triangle_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context> cr) {
    cr->set_source_rgb(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    cr->set_line_width(4.0);
    cr->move_to(0, 0);
    cr->line_to(30, 30);
    cr->stroke();
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.CENSORED.sierpinski");
    
    auto builder = Gtk::Builder::create_from_file("sierpinski.glade");
    
    builder->get_widget("W_Main", W_Main);
    builder->get_widget("D_Triangle", D_Triangle);
    builder->get_widget("B_Draw", B_Draw);
    builder->get_widget("A_Depth", A_Depth);
    
    D_Triangle->signal_draw().connect(sigc::ptr_fun(on_D_Triangle_draw));
    
    app->run(*W_Main);
}
```

Now here's the odd thing: Apparently, the "on_D_Triangle_draw" function HAS TO return an integer! I first tried to make it a void function, but then the compiler returned a totally incomprehensible error message.

Can someone explain to me what is going on here? Further, is `0` the right value to return (in the sense of "best practice")?

EDIT: Here is the (very verbose) error message, as requested:

```
In file included from /usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal_base.h:27,
                 from /usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/signal.h:8,
                 from /usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/sigc++.h:123,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/thread.h:50,
                 from /usr/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm.h:103,
                 from sierpinski.cpp:1:
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/functors/slot.h: In instantiation of ‘static T_return sigc::internal::slot_call1<T_functor, T_return, T_arg1>::call_it(sigc::internal::slot_rep*, sigc::type_trait_take_t<T_arg3>) [with T_functor = sigc::pointer_functor1<Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>, void>; T_return = bool; T_arg1 = const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>&; sigc::type_trait_take_t<T_arg3> = const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>&]’:
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/functors/slot.h:177:56:   required from ‘static void* (* sigc::internal::slot_call1<T_functor, T_return, T_arg1>::address())(void*) [with T_functor = sigc::pointer_functor1<Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>, void>; T_return = bool; T_arg1 = const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>&; sigc::internal::hook = void* (*)(void*)]’
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/functors/slot.h:679:90:   required from ‘sigc::slot1<T_return, T_arg1>::slot1(const T_functor&) [with T_functor = sigc::pointer_functor1<Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>, void>; T_return = bool; T_arg1 = const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>&]’
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/functors/slot.h:1843:26:   required from ‘sigc::slot<T_return, T_arg1, sigc::nil, sigc::nil, sigc::nil, sigc::nil, sigc::nil, sigc::nil>::slot(const T_functor&) [with T_functor = sigc::pointer_functor1<Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>, void>; T_return = bool; T_arg1 = const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>&]’
sierpinski.cpp:40:38:   required from here
/usr/include/sigc++-2.0/sigc++/functors/slot.h:170:16: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
  169 |       return (typed_rep->functor_).SIGC_WORKAROUND_OPERATOR_PARENTHESES<type_trait_take_t<T_arg1>>
      |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  170 |                (a_1);
      |                ^~~~~
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `int` not `gboolean`?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268637/c-gtk3-draw-event-for-multiple-widgets#11269580

Comment: What error message did you get when you tried to have a `void` return type?

Comment: `gboolean` does compile as well.

Comment: @SolomonUcko I've included the error message.

Comment: *"the (very verbose) error message"* -- While the message is verbose, I would not go as far as "very" verbose. It's actually pretty tame compared to some of the error messages produced when templates are involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the gtkm-3 documentation](http://transit.iut2.upmf-grenoble.fr/doc/gtkmm-3.0/reference/html/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#ab0a7d34fe7ae7a83fdb1e1ddd223e8f4):

> **Slot Prototype:**
> `bool on_my_draw(const ::Cairo::RefPtr< ::Cairo::Context>& cr)`

This signal is expected to return a value, either a `bool` or something convertible to `bool`. Returning `int` is acceptable, but `void` is not.

> **Returns**
> `true` to stop other handlers from being invoked for the event. `false` to propagate the event further.

If you return zero (false), other handlers may be invoked. If you return non-zero (true), then no other handlers will be invoked. You can read the return value as "job done".